# Create animation or GIF with point plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create an animation or GIF that shows the evolution of an environmental condition over time. Basically, I have a dataset (example below) with year, value of the environmental condition, unit, and coordinates.

| year | condition | unit | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1945 | -0.120148 | TSS | 41.36531 | 41.67889 |
| 1948 | 0.274646 | TSS | 30.45368 | -87.99042 |
| 1948 | 0.074794 | TSS | 30.45368 | -87.99042 |
| 1975 | -0.102050 | TSS | 38.10541 | -122.06782 |
| 1979 | -0.169886 | NTU | 29.77048 | -84.91630 |

Complete dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XQ95KP_x-kbq_wdmpfpCiOonF-RoFsU1/view?usp=sharing

I am using ggplot2 to create the plots comprising year gaps. Here is the code I am using to plot the variation from 1945 to 1980:

```
`ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = world, map = world,aes(long, lat, map_id = region),color = "seashell2", fill = "seashell", size = 0.3, alpha=0.9)+
  geom_point(data = mapa_variacao_anual_45_80,aes(Long, Lat, color = med_turb),size=2, shape=16, position = position_jitter(width = 8)) + 
  labs(title = "1945 to 1980")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  scale_colour_gradient( low = "darkgreen",    high = "red")+
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")+
  theme(legend.title= element_blank())+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'aliceblue', colour = 'gray'))`
```

My plan is to have several plots with determined year ranges and in the end combine all of them in sequence to show temporal variation.
Is there an easy way to combine the plots? I have been looking for solutions online but they seem not to suit my goal or are just too complicated.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get `gganimate` to handle the animation for you:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

world <- map_data("world")

mapa_variacao_anual_45_80$frames <- as.numeric(
   factor(mapa_variacao_anual_45_80$year))

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_map(data = world, map = world,
           aes(long, lat, map_id = region),
           color = "seashell2", fill = "seashell", size = 0.3, alpha = 0.9)+
  geom_point(data = mapa_variacao_anual_45_80, 
             aes(Long, Lat, color = med_turb),
             size = 2, shape = 16, position = position_jitter(width = 8)) + 
  labs(title = "1945 to 1980")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  scale_colour_gradient( low = "darkgreen", high = "red") +
  geom_text(data = mapa_variacao_anual_45_80,
            aes(x = -180, y = 65, label = year), hjust = 0, size = 8,
            check_overlap = TRUE) +
  xlab("Longitude") + 
  ylab("Latitude")+
  theme(legend.title= element_blank())+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'aliceblue', colour = 'gray')) +
  transition_events(mapa_variacao_anual_45_80$frames,
                    enter_length = 1, exit_length = 1) 

anim_save("map.gif", p, device = "ragg_png", duration = 20, fps = 30,
          width = 900, height = 450)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how did it but I ended up editing your answer and now, there is a missing part at it. Could you please insert the text I removed?

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I just plotted the map following your code and it returns a kind of a "running point" and, unfortunately, that's not what I need. Is there something that can be changed in the code to reach something like this?:  https://blogs-images.forbes.com/brianbrettschneider/files/2018/09/VerificationAnimation.gif?

Comment: @PatriciaNunes if you are able to share your data I could show you how to achieve a similar result. It's difficult with a single point over several years. To stop the fade in / fade out you could try removing the `enter_fade()` and `exit_fade()` lines

Comment: Since my dataset is long, I just added a link to the file.

Comment: @PatriciaNunes see my update - are you looking for something like that?

Comment: Exactly that! Thank you! Is there a way to slow down the points change?

Comment: Increase the duration in `anim_save`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a series of png files and assemble them into an animation with the **gifski** package:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gifski)

for(i in 1:30){
  gg <- ggplot(......)
  ggsave(sprintf("myplot%03d.png", i), gg)
}

png_files <- Sys.glob("myplot*.png")

gifski(
  png_files,
  "myanimation.gif",
  width = 400, height = 400,
  delay = 1/5 # 5 images per second
)

file.remove(png_files)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have now the individual plots but I didn't understand how to indicate them in the code. How can I do this?